# Illegal vector component name "x" (metal)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, metal, metalkit

with Metal, at runtime, when I try to compile my shader I receive the error

> Error: Illegal vector component name 'x'

[image]

It's work well when In macos 10.14/10.15 but **on macos 10.11 on old mac mini it's crash!** any idea why ?

```
using namespace metal;

struct Vertex {
  packed_float3 position;
};

struct ProjectedVertex {
  float4 position [[position]];
};

vertex ProjectedVertex vertexShader(constant Vertex *vertexArray [[buffer(0)]],
                                    const unsigned int vertexId [[vertex_id]],
                                    constant float4x4 &MVPMatrix [[buffer(1)]]) {
  Vertex in = vertexArray[vertexId];
  ProjectedVertex out;
  out.position = float4(in.position.x, in.position.y, in.position.z, 1) * MVPMatrix;
  return out;
}
```

Comment: Please provide your shader code.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 I just updated the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to Metal 2.1, accessing the named components of a packed vector type is not permitted in Metal Shading Language.

To work around this, either access such elements via subscripting, or by creating a local variable of the corresponding non-packed type:

```
out.position = float4(in.position[0], in.position[1], in.position[2], 1) * MVPMatrix;

// OR:

float3 position = in.position;
out.position = float4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1) * MVPMatrix;
```

Comment: THANKS! but how did you get to know this? it's written no where :(

Comment: @loki [MSL](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf) **2.2.3 Packed Vector Types**

Comment: @warrenm how can I do with instruction like position.xy? Is there a solution similar in.position[x] that can help me without doing float3 position = in.position; ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.